# Determining general solution from ref

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $u_1,u_2,u_3$, and $v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the RREF of $(u_1 |u_2 |u_3 |v)$ is \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&1\\0&1&2&-2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} how can I express v in terms of $u_1,u_2$,and $u_3$? I know that $u_1-u_3 =v$ and $u_2+2u_3 =-2v$.

Since the third column is a nonpivotal column, I can introduce an arbitrarily chosen parameter, say $t$, then $u_2 = -2v+2t$ and $u_1= v+t$.
(I was stuck here since I do not know how to express $v$ in terms of $u_1,u_2$, and $u_3$.)

Comment: The order of your columns implies that you want $u_1$ and $u_2$ in terms of the others. If you want to isolate $v$, then why not put the $v$ column first, then reduce the matrix?

Comment: Í figure out another way using linear combination, so a(1,0,0)+b(0,1,2)+c(-1,2,0)=v

Comment: and substituting what I just found above, I get (1+t)u1 - 2(1+t)u2 + tu3 = v for any real number

Comment: is this is the correct approach?

Comment: Well, before going on, why is it that you want to express $v$ in terms of the others? From your description of the problem, it sounds like you're just trying to solve the system, and in that case you would just introduce another arbitrary parameter, say $s$, with $v=s$. This is what you did for $u_3$; the same reasoning applies to $v$. But if you really do want to express $v$ in terms of the others, then whatever you do to solve the system amounts to finding another RREF but with a pivotal $v$ column.

Comment: The exercise in my textbook ask us to find v in terms of u1,u2 and u3. and the answer given for this question is v = (1+t)u1 - 2(1+t)u2 + tu3 for any real number t, so can I assume my approach is correct?

Comment: Hmm. Is there a vertical bar missing in your matrix? Is it supposed to be $$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&0&-1&1\\0&1&2&-2\\0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]?$$
I've been wondering why you have $v=u_1-u_3$; that would explain it. In that case, forget what I said about introducing another parameter for $v$. So in that first line, $v=u_1-u_3$, you already have $v$ in terms of $u_1, u_2$, and $u_3$. That's what I would give as an answer. To be thorough, deal with the second equation by adding twice the first row to the second: this gives $2u_1+u_2=0$, which doesn't affect $v$ at all.

Comment: Yes,there is a vertical bar in the matrix. But how come the answer given is  v = (1+t)u1 - 2(1+t)u2 + tu3? I have no idea how to derive this answer.

Comment: Good question. To be honest, I would just move on rather than trying to make sense of your textbook here. Incidentally, you can try solving it on [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Bu1-u3%3Dv%2C+u2%2B2u3%3D-2v%7D+for+v): it comes up with the solution $v=-\frac12u_2-u_3,\  u_1=-\frac12u_2$, which is just another way of saying $v=u_1-u_3$.